# Testing failing when running selenium grid using fiddler core

Tags: selenium, fiddlercore

I am using fiddler core to inject headers on web requests. 
The tests run fine with a single thread. However when running the tests with multiple threads. The tests fails.

Its seems that fiddler core is not able to handle multiple instances.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

FiddlerCore, by design, operates on multiple network requests in parallel. The most likely explanation is that your own code inside FiddlerCore isn't threadsafe.